# System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Visual studio 2012 MVC 4 connecting to the database SQL SERVER Management Studio 2012.

I am getting below exception

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open.

```
public Actionresult Details(int id) {EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(x => x.EmployeeId == id); return View(employee);}
```

Also sometimes i get following exception while using connection string

```
 <connectionStrings> <add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="server=.; database=Sample; integrated security=SSPI"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot open database "Sample" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.

Comment: That's all a bit strange. First, IIS by default doesn't use the `SYSTEM` user; second: `SYSTEM` should have access to the database, because it has access to everything. Please first check the datbase permisstions. Does the mentioned user have enough permissions?

Comment: Yes... Sir.. All the permission are granted for the user.. Is it like my connection string should have server name as .\MSSQLSERVER??

Comment: My issue is resolved i just re added EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll, and also added  [Table("Employee")] in models